# Streaming api when Case (700 fields) is closed

Tags: apex, streaming-api

I would like to use the streaming api for the following use case,

***"When a case is closed the complete object should be published. Case object contains more than 700 fields'***

After a quick investigation, it seems there are different options:

1. **Change data capture (CDC)**. No valid because we can not add rules (case is closed)
2. **Pushtopics**. SOQL with no more 1300 characters...in this case we have 700 fields
3. **Platform Events**. I think this is the best solution creating one platform event with only one field (payload) and populate it with a json that contains all the case fields. The problem could be if the payload length is more than the platform event length field. Create 700 fields in the platform event is insane.

What do you think? One of this options or another one?

Thanks

Comment: What about pushing only record Id, and then doing fetch of all the fields based on record id from client side?

Comment: yeah, that's another valid option, but then we need to execute one api call per record Id...increasing the number of daily api calls..

Comment: What's a real-world use case that is going to require all 700 fields?

Comment: Don’t ask...hahaha

Comment: If you need some sort of replication, consider using the replication api methods getUpdated and getDeleted. From there, it's a simple matter of using retrieve calls to get up to 2k records at once with all the fields, all for the cost of a single API call.

Comment: If that sounds like overkill, it may be you simply won't be using that many API calls per day after all. For example, in our org, we have some odd 15,000,000 api calls daily, and to even get close to that, we'd have to have every support person handle over 30,000 cases per day (back-of-a-napkin calculations, not actual values). Moral of the story, you may want to run reports before you decide that simple replication is not an option, or streaming is too expensive.